# Problems with checking existing data in database tables c#

Tags: c#

Just got into c# and I am struggling with databases a bit. I managed to write a code for adding a new "User" values but I keep failing to check the old ones. What I want it to do is to check textbox (dodajsifruprof) and see if there is the same value inside the database for Sifra_Prof, if so it should block the insert of another user with the same Sifra_Prof value. Code below is the latest thing I tried and it "should" give me the desired result but it just lets me insert new users with same SIfra_Prof value.

```
public partial class Form2Add_Update : Form
{
    SqlConnection veza = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Sniprep\Documents\DrugiDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter adp;
    DataTable dt;

    private void btnDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dodajsifraprof.Text == "" || dodajimeprof.Text == "" || dodajprezimeprof.Text == "" || dodajjmbgprof.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EmptyTextBoxFail");
        }
        else
        {
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Sifra_Prof from Profesor where Sifra_Prof ='" + dodajsifraprof + "'", veza);
            dt = new DataTable();
            veza.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1) 
            {
               MessageBox.Show("CheckFail");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Profesor(Sifra_Prof,Ime_Prof,Prezime_Prof,JMBG_Prof) values ('" + dodajsifraprof.Text + "','" + dodajimeprof.Text + "','" + dodajprezimeprof.Text + "','" + dodajjmbgprof.Text + "')", veza);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    txtclear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        veza.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think have a typo... you want to use `dodajsifraprof.Text`. your are simply using `dodajsifraprof` in your select statement

Comment: Also you should use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation to avoid sql injection. Someone could just enter sql that will delete all your professors, they would not like it